# JavaFX GraphicsContext change text size

Tags: canvas, fonts, javafx, pane, graphicscontext

I would like to be able to change the font size and possibly the font itself before the strokeText() method is called. I can change the color but I don't see anyway to change the font.

```
Pane canvas = new Pane();
GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
gc.setStroke(Color.WHITE);
gc.strokeText("Hello", 1, 1);
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can set the GraphicsContext's font and font size by calling the [setFont](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html#setFont%28javafx.scene.text.Font%29) method before your strokeText call.

```
gc.setFont(new Font(fontName, fontSize));
```

Comment: Apparently I am blind as I didn't even see that.  Thanks for the answer.